# How to find canonical form of $u_{xx}+36u_{xy}+243u_{yy}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I need to find the canonical form of $$u_{xx}+36u_{xy}+243u_{yy}=0$$ and find the general solution but I have no idea how to find the canonical form, I am new to the subject in general, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This document](http://faculty.uml.edu/spennell/Teaching/PDE/classification.pdf) may help

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @AlainRemillard I've found out that the equation is hyperbolic, I've written it down as $u_{ξξ}+36u_{ξη}+243u_{ηη}=0$ but I don't understand how it is solved using η and ξ from that point on, everything I read about is very confusing, I was wondering if there was some dumbed down way to approach solving it

Comment: You're looking for a change of variables $(x,y)\to (\xi,\eta)$ such that the only second partial derivative that appears is the mixed partial $u_{\xi\eta}$. A systematic way to proceed is via characteristics. If you're not knowledgeable about that, though, try considering a generic linear transformation \begin{align} \xi &= a x+b y, \\ \eta & = c x+d y.\end{align} Use that to rewrite your PDE in terms of $(\xi,\eta)$ and look for $a,b,c,d$ which eliminate all but the mixed partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

$x^2+36x y +243 y^2 = (x+9y)(x+27 y)$

then

$$
(\partial_x+9\partial_y)(\partial_x+27\partial_y)u = 0
$$

so we can proceed as

$$
(\partial_x+9\partial_y)v=0\\
(\partial_x+27\partial_y)u = v
$$

Also can be easily solved after a coordinates change. Making the change of coordinates
$$
\xi = a_1 x + b_1 y\\
\eta = a_2 x+ b_2 y
$$

we get at

$$
(a_2^2+36a_2b_2+243 b_2^2)u_{\eta\eta}+2(a_1a_2+18a_2b_1+243b_1b_2)u_{\xi\eta}+(a_1^2+36a_1b_1+243 b_1^2)u_{\xi\xi}=0
$$

and now choosing

$$
a_1 = -9b_1\\
a_2 = -27b_2
$$

we finally arrive at the simpler version

$$
u_{\xi\eta}(\xi,\eta)=0
$$

and thus

$$
u(\xi,\eta) = \phi(\xi)+\theta(\eta)
$$